# Input Array is not being validated if it contains more than one value in laravel custom validation

Tags: php, laravel

Senario:

- Title under each category will be unique.
- I want to write a custom validator which cheks if same title with category exists.

**Problem:**

If I add one title it validates the uniqeness under same category. Such:
[image: It is working]

But if I add multiple rows, validation does not work. Such:
[image]

I think foreach in 'CategoryResolverTitle' file is being exicuted once. What is the solution.
My Form

```
<label for="Title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="names[]" class="form-control">
```

My Custom Validator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Models\QueryManagement\CategoryResolver;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CategoryTitle implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        foreach ($value as $element) {
            return !Category::whereDepartmentId(request('department'))->whereName($element)->exists();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Title under same category must be unique';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk symbol **(*)** is used to check values in the array, not the `array` itself.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
"names.*"  => "required|string|distinct|min:3",
]);
```

In the example above:

- "names" must be an array with at least 3 elements,
- values in the "names" array must be distinct (unique) strings, at least 3 characters long.

---

**EDIT**: Since Laravel 5.5 you can call validate() method directly on Request object like so:

```
$data = $request->validate([
"name.*"  => "required|string|distinct|min:3",
 ]);
```

also follow this [url](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-nested-array-input) for more details

Answer (score 2):

You current `passes()` function seems to be faulty. It will only start the loop once, then return the result of the first check immediately. A better way would be:

```
foreach ($value as $element) {
   if(Category::whereDepartmentId(request('department'))->whereName($element)->exists()){
      return false;
   }
}
return true;
```

Comment: If I understand OPs requirements correctly, you need to remove the `!` in the `if` to fail the validation if at least one category of the same name exists. May be wrong though, it's not really clear from the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-nested-array-input) for this. There's a specific validation rule that can achieve database uniqueness:

```
$request->validate([
   "names.*" => Rule::unique('categories', 'name')->where(function ($q) {
         $q->where('department_id', request('department'));
    })
]);
```